# How to convert QString to QDomElement?

Tags: mysql, qt, qtxml

I've `QDomElement` object converted to QString via `element.text()` method and stored in mysql database in text format. I've a problem while extracting it from database, because having extracted from database it has a format of QString, so I need to convert it again to QDomElement in order to further implement smth with that object. How can I do this?

Comment: The text()-method will not return the complete element, only the content.

Comment: So what do I need (any methods in Qt) to get the whole content of xml?

Comment: Whole xml content or just an element? Also, why do you store the xml in the database rather than in friendlier format?

Comment: Whole one! Any suggestions (I', about friendlier format)?

Comment: There's QDomNode::save()

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string into a QDomDocument and then extract the whole tree:

```
QString input("<xml></xml>");
QDomDocument xmlDoc;
xmlDoc.setContent(input);
QDomElement output = xmlDoc.firstChild().toElement();
```