# Checking if root element exist in Xml using qt c++

Tags: c++, xml, qt

> **I have an Xml file:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <AppConfig>
 <DefaultCulture></DefaultCulture>
 <StartupMessageTitle></StartupMessageTitle>
 <StartupMessageText></StartupMessageText>
 <StartupMessageIcon>Information</StartupMessageIcon>
 <DefaultProfileSettings>
 <DriverName>wia</DriverName>
 <UseNativeUI>false</UseNativeUI>
 <IconID>0</IconID>
 <MaxQuality>false</MaxQuality>
 <AfterScanScale>OneToOne</AfterScanScale>
 <Brightness>0</Brightness>
 <Contrast>0</Contrast>
 <BitDepth>C24Bit</BitDepth>
 <PageAlign>Left</PageAlign>
 <PageSize>Letter</PageSize>
 <Resolution>Dpi100</Resolution>
 <PaperSource>Glass</PaperSource>
 </DefaultProfileSettings>
 <!--
 <AutoSaveSettings>
 <FilePath></FilePath>
 <ClearImagesAfterSaving>false</ClearImagesAfterSaving>
 <Separator>FilePerPage</Separator>
 </AutoSaveSettings>
  -->
 </AppConfig>
```

> I need to check if root elements "AutoSaveSettings" exists in xml using qt c++ . if the root elements exists then remove the commented line before  and after the Auto save settings? How can we do it in qt c++. How do I perform this operation in c++.Check if exists start element or root element

```
  #include <QtCore>
  #include <QtXml/QDomDocument>
  #include <QDebug>
  #include <QFile>
  #include <QXmlStreamReader>

  bool elementExists(const QFile &file, const QString &elementName)      
  {

     QXmlStreamReader reader(&file);

     while (reader.readNextStartElement())
      {
        if(reader.name() == elementName)
         {
           return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
   }

  int main(int argc,char *argv[])
   {
     QCoreApplication a(argc,argv);

     QDomDocument document;
     QFile file = "C:/Program Files (x86)/NAPS2/appsettings.xml";
     if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
     {
         qDebug()<<"Failed to open the file";
         return -1;
     }
     else{
         if(!document.setContent(&file))
         {
             qDebug()<< "Failed to load Document";
             return -1;
         }
         file.close();
     }

     elementExists(file,"AutoSaveSettings");

     qDebug()<< "Finished";

     return a.exec();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using QXmlStreamReader ? Because i can see there is a method  bool isComment() const;  Sorry i won't put code as an answer since i am not sure the QXmlStreamReader it will work. You can see an example in documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html

Comment: First I need to find out If "AutoSaveSettings" exists?How to i Do that

Comment: [DOM Parser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/xml-dom-tml.html) might be easier to use. Basic idea: enumerate each child node, check if it is `QDomComment`, use `QDomComment::data()` to get comment string. Convert the string into `QDomElement` using [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39011345/7571258) and insert new element at appropriate place in document.

Comment: _First I need to find out If "AutoSaveSettings"_ - You have to enumerate all nodes and check if it is comment node, then compare string content. Comment is only string, you can't find it directly.

Comment: i posted some code.  Tell me if it works

Comment: does that mean we need to iterate through all nodes first

Comment: Maybe there is a better way that doesn't require iterating through all document. If i find something better, i will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
bool elementExists( QFile & file, const QString & elementName){

    QXmlStreamReader reader (&file);

    while (reader.readNextStartElement()){
        if(reader.name() == elementName) return true; 
       //elementName should be "AutoSaveSettings"
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Edit :** an alternative way could be using QDomDocument

Not recomanded because QDomDocument is not actively maintained anymore

```
bool elementExists( QFile & file,const QString & elementName){

    QDomDocument reader;
    reader.setContent(&file, true);
    QDomNodeList elementList =  reader.elementsByTagName(elementName);
    return elementList.size()>0;
}
```

Comment: This is not working gives an error cannot convert Qfile to QIOdevice

Comment: strange! Have you included QFile ?

Comment: In the second approach  it gives error cannont convert from Qfile to Qbyteerror

Comment: ok i forgot to put the second argument, which is a bool, in setContent that's why

Comment: As [stated in the documentation,](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-module.html) `QDomDocument` should not be used in new code: "The module is not actively maintained anymore. Please use the QXmlStreamReader and QXmlStreamWriter classes in Qt Core instead."

Comment: @ cyley : for the first function have you put const for QFile? Because if so that is the problem. You should remove const.